# Can I get more than one association bonus awarded on all my accounts?

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts, association-bonus

On Stack Overflow I crossed 200 and got 100 rep association on all accounts.

Now, if I cross 200 on Mathematics (I am on 188 reputation now) then will I get another 100 rep association bonus on all of my accounts?

Comment: No​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Or rather. What happens when you get 200 on 2 sites? Now you have 200 on all 100+ sites. If you got the bonus for all of them, you'll have 10k on all sites.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nope. You get the association bonus *once*.

The *first time* one of your accounts crosses 200 rep, you get a +100 bonus on all sites one which you have an account. If you make an account on another site after this, you start of with 101 rep on that site as well.

The 100 rep is to prevent some new-user barriers from hampering you on the site. For example, we can safely assume that most people have understood (at least partially) what comments are for by the time they reach 200, and don't need to earn the right to comment again and again.

Comment: Quite a good explanation...